# How to access functions inside a record inside a module

Tags: coq

I am trying to do modular arithmetic in Coq. I notice there is the [ZModulo](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.Cyclic.ZModulo.ZModulo.html) library which I attempt to import and create the `ZModuloCyclicType` Module.

```
Require Import Utf8_core.
Require Import ZArith_base.
Require Import Coq.Numbers.Cyclic.ZModulo.ZModulo.

Ltac positive_ne1 :=
  match goal with
  | [ |- ?p ≠ 1%positive ] => unfold not; intro H; inversion H
  end.

Module Positive8 : PositiveNotOne.
  Definition p := 8%positive.
  Theorem not_one : p ≠ 1%positive. 
  Proof. positive_ne1. Qed.
End Positive8.
Module ZquotZ8 := ZModuloCyclicType(Positive8).
Export ZquotZ8.
```

Now, I want to access the `succ` operation which is inside the record `Instance zmod_ops : ZnZ.Ops Z := ZnZ.MkOps`. However,

```
Check ZquotZ8.ops.succ. (* Error: The reference ZquotZ8_ops.succ was not found in the current environment. *)
Check ZquotZ8.ops.(succ). (* Error: The term "ops" has type "ZnZ.Ops t" while it is expected to have type "Z". *)

Definition ZquotZ8_ops : ZnZ.Ops Z := zmod_ops 8.
Check ZquotZ8_ops.succ. (* Error: The reference ZquotZ8_ops.succ was not found in the current environment. *)
Check ZquotZ8_ops.(succ). (* Error: The term "ZquotZ8_ops" has type "ZnZ.Ops Z" while it is expected to have type "Z". *)
```

My question is: how can I access this instance of `succ` instead of the one defined in `Coq.Numbers.Cyclic.ZModulo.ZModulo.`?

What I want is `Compute succ_Z8 255 = 0%Z : Z` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're set on a record selection, it's

```
Require Import Coq.Numbers.Cyclic.Abstract.CyclicAxioms.

ZquotZ8.ops.(@ZnZ.succ _)
(* equivalent to *)
@ZnZ.succ _ ZquotZ8.ops
```

But, the thing is, `ZnZ.Ops` is a `Class`, not just a record, `ZquotZ8.ops` is an `Instance`, and `ZnZ.succ` can find `ZquotZ8.ops` implicitly because you have used `Export ZquotZ8`. So it's just

```
ZnZ.succ
```

However, I think you also need to change the header of `Positive8` to

```
(* NOT            : *)
Module Positive8 <: PositiveNotOne.
```

Otherwise, `Positive8.p` is opaque, and you cannot compute with it. Once that's done, you get

```
Compute (ZnZ.compare (ZnZ.succ 255%Z) 0%Z).
(* = Eq *)
```

Note that `succ` doesn't roll over; here, it returns `256%Z`. `ZnZ.to_Z` will actually compute the remainder, or you can use `succ_c`.